# Payum custom gateway

Tags: php, symfony, payum

I want to use a new gateway with payum but I have confused.

I have a flowchart of a transaction, in a regular way I know how to implement it but I don't know how to implement it in payum way.
[image]

What I want is, that somebody tells me that :

- how many Payum action I need ?
- how many controller action I need ?
- Do I need a new gatewayFoctory or a new gateway or both ?
- what is different between afterUrl and taregtUrl ?
- In Docs,we have an object named "model" !, what's the purpose of it?

Comment: The easiest way to get started with custom gateway is to copy this repository https://github.com/Payum/Skeleton and start changing stuff there.

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar , I have tried It but I still can't figure it out. and there is no sample implementation of custom gateway any where even in the payum sandbox.

Comment: the easiest way to get started with a custom gateway is to type `composer create-project payum/skeleton`

Comment: did you manage to solve this? Please either accept an answer or take the time to write your own and accept it.

Comment: @Hafenkranich Yes I'm working on it,but the solution is not complete yet.

Answer (score 1):

At [Payum getting started](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/get-it-started.md) it looks like all you actually need is 3 steps/actions:

**prepare**

- Set values
- Ask for and fetch target token from payum
- Redirect (url to redirect to is returned within the token.)
- The redirect url is a payum url
- Payum will preprocess payment stuff
- Payum will redirect to your capture method

**capture**

- Actually tell payum to process the request (authentication yourself with the token)
- Burn token
- Redirect to done method (actually redirecting to Payum and Payum is redirecting to your done method)

**done**

- Check if it went sucessfully
- Do stuff

Other Stuff

- `getTargetUrl` is the URL returned by payum, where you redirect to
  after `prepare`
- `getAfterUrl()` is the URL returned by payum, where
  you redirect to after `capture`
- [Examples of other gateways can be found here](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/supported-gateways.md) if you want to integrate them you define a new gateway (see config file for KlarnaCheckout e.g.)
- If you want to [add another payment provider you start here](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/develop-gateway-with-payum.md) using composer you build a new gatewayFactory (and afterwards define the gateway like above)